# What's the conjugate of a matrix function?

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-equations

As we all know, the conjugate of a function for a vector $\textbf{x}$ is
$$
f^*(\textbf{y})=sup(\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x}-f(\textbf{x}))
$$
what's the conjugate of a function for a matrix $\textbf{X}$?
what's the $f^*(\textbf{Y})$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: A standard inner product on $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$ is $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{tr}(A^T B) = \text{vec}(A) \cdot \text{vec}(B)$. If $f: \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R$ is convex, it would be natural to define $f^*(Y) = \sup_{X} \langle X, Y \rangle - f(X)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.